# Error in converting class to template class

Tags: c++, templates

**Code is a little long because I can't really trace the source of the error, so I'm not sure how much more I can remove (still new to C++ templates)**

Already omitted are member functions and methods that I've also converted to templates, I don't think they're relevant for the error.

Below was a given class that I've been converting to an abstract template class, when compiled, I get the following compile-time error:

> 1.cpp:116:3: error: no matching function for call to 'testPFArrayD'
>                   testPFArrayD();
>
> 1.cpp:87:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template
>         argument 'T' void testPFArrayD()

Line 166 is the **Main()** call for the function testPFArrayD(). The actual purpose of the class isn't very important in this case, I just need to know the issue in converting it to a template.

The full-length, original source code (not converted to a template) for the class is [here](https://pastebin.com/ftdgTsYQ)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class PFArrayD
{
    public:
        PFArrayD();
        PFArrayD(int capacityValue);
        PFArrayD(const PFArrayD& pfaObject);
        void addElement(T element);
        bool full() const { return (capacity == used); }
        int getCapacity() const { return capacity; }
        int getNumberUsed() const { return used; }
        void emptyArray() { used = 0; }
        double& operator[](T index);
        PFArrayD& operator =(const PFArrayD& rightSide);
        ~PFArrayD();
    private:
        double *a; 
        int capacity; 
        int used; 
};

template <typename T>
PFArrayD<T>::PFArrayD() :capacity(50), used(0)
{
    a = new T[capacity];
}

template <typename T>
void testPFArrayD()
{
    int cap;
    cout << "Enter capacity of this super array: ";
    cin >> cap;
    PFArrayD() temp (cap); //?????????????????
    cout << "Enter up to " << cap << " nonnegative numbers. \n";
    cout << "Place a negative number at the end. \n";
    double next;
    cin >> next;
    while ((next >= 0) && (!temp.full())) 
    {
        temp.addElement(next);
        cin >> next;
    }
    cout << "You entered the following " << temp.getNumberUsed() << " numbers:\n";
    int index;
    int count = temp.getNumberUsed();
    for (index = 0; index < count; index++)
        cout << temp[index] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "(plus a sentinel value.)\n";
}

int main() 
{
    cout << "This program tests the class PFArrayD.\n";
    char ans;
    do {
        testPFArrayD();
        cout << "Test again? (y/n) ";
        cin >> ans;
    } while ((ans == 'y') || (ans == 'Y'));
    //system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*couldn't infer template argument 'T'*" is pretty clear. The compiler doesn't know what T should be. Do you?

Comment: I added the template header to this function because it calls the PFArrayD class within its body, which is a template class.

Comment: @Jad That is a poor excuse for making something a template. You might be right that eventually it will need to be a template, but don't jump the gun. Don't convert something to be a template until doing so accomplishes something. (On a related note, when `testPFArrayD` tries to instantiate a `PFArrayD`, what is the template parameter for `PFArrayD` supposed to be?)

Comment: @JaMiT The rest of the methods/functions belonging to the PFArrayD class which are not shown above do indeed need to be templates, for that reason the entire PFArrayD class needs to be given a template header and be one big template. And since this function instantiates an object of that template class, it in turn also needs to be given a template header.

Comment: @Jad No, that by itself does not mean the function needs to be a template. A non-template function is fully capable of instantiating a templated class. For example, `int main() { std::vector<int> X; }` is valid. *(You likely will make `testPFArrayD` a template at some point, but since you're not at that point yet, you don't know how to resolve the compiler error you're facing. Don't skip steps.)*

Comment: @JaMiT If I remove that template header and compile I get an error saying that the call for the PFArrayD class needs a template argument

Comment: @Jad Correct. Address that first. (Making the function a template did not fix it; you just caused the compiler to report new errors before it got to that one. C.f. [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)) Probably start with `PFArrayD<double> temp;` as a stopgap measure until you verify that your class template is defined correctly.

Comment: Hmm.. there is a weirdness factor here in that the new errors are on later lines in the source code. That is rare except when dealing with templates. So I'll offer a tidbit and rely less on trust: in the code you posted, change the line `testPFArrayD();` to `testPFArrayD<double>();` and observe that the error you were trying to fix is once again the first error reported by the compiler. You don't need to fix the fix; you need a new fix to the original problem.

Comment: @JaMiT , when passing in types such as double I find errors with the rest of my code in that it doesn't play well with other class methods not shown above, could I show you those in chat?

Comment: @Jad Relying on me might end up taking a while (case in point: this past week). It might be better to isolate those errors and post a question for each of them, if you haven't already resolved them. (Or try some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) -- these might be the types of errors where you see what is wrong when you try to explain to someone why it's right.)